Identify error in multiple Insert statements and rollback
I have a scenario where I have to insert into 10 tables. The code looks like this:
create or replace procedure insert_into_tbls
as
begin
    savepoint s1;
    insert into tab1;
    insert into tab2;
    insert into tab3;
    insert into tab4;
    insert into tab5;
    savepoint s2;
    insert into tab6;
    insert into tab7;
    insert into tab8;
    insert into tab9;
    insert into tab10;
exception
    when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('Error Occurred');
    rollback to s1; -- or rollback to s2;
end

If there is an error in first 5 inserts, I want to rollback to savepoint s1.
If there is an error in inserting into tables 6-10, then I want to rollback to s2.
Is there a way to identify whether the error is occurring in the first 5 inserts or last 5 inserts?
This was asked to me in the interview. Was not able to answer.

sounds like a question for asktom.oracle.com I'd ask it there.

You can nest blocks for this
create or replace procedure insert_into_tbls
as
begin
  begin
    savepoint s1;
    insert into tab1;
    insert into tab2;
    insert into tab3;
    insert into tab4;
    insert into tab5;
 exception 
    when others then
      rollback to s1;
      return;
 end;
 begin
    savepoint s2;
    insert into tab6;
    insert into tab7;
    insert into tab8;
    insert into tab9;
    insert into tab10;
exception
    when others then
    rollback to s2;
end

but in reality, it might just be easier to set a variable indicating where you're up to (which would probably be part of a debugging facilty anyway)
The other thing to remember is that PLSQL calls implicitly set savepoints so that they logically appear as single unit of work, eg
SQL> create table t ( x int );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure p1 is
  3  begin
  4    insert into t values (1);
  5    insert into t values (2);
  6    insert into t values (3);
  7    insert into t values (4);
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure p2 is
  3    x int;
  4  begin
  5    insert into t values (5);
  6    insert into t values (6);
  7    insert into t values (7);
  8    insert into t values (8);
  9    x := 1/0;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure p3 is
  3  begin
  4    p1;
  5    p2;
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> exec p3;
BEGIN p3; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at "MCDONAC.P2", line 8
ORA-06512: at "MCDONAC.P3", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL> select * from t;

no rows selected

